# Schema design for MongoDB pre-aggregated reports

Tags: mongodb, reporting, data-modeling

I'm following the official MongoDB docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) about pre-aggregated reports. According to the tutorial, a pre-aggregated document should look like this:

```
{
  _id: "20101010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
  metadata: {
    date: ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z"),
    site: "site-1",
    page: "/apache_pb.gif" },
  hourly: {
    "0": 227850,
    "1": 210231,
    ...
    "23": 20457 },
  minute: {
    "0": {
        "0": 3612,
        "1": 3241,
        ...
        "59": 2130 },
    "1": {
        "0": ...,
    },
    ...
    "23": {
        "59": 2819 }
  }
}
```

The thing is that I'm currently using this approach, and I already have some data stored this way. But now I want to add another dimension in the metadata subdocument and I was reconsidering the whole thing.

My question is: is there a reason to build the _id attribute with the same information stored in the metadata attribute? Wouldn't be enough to create a compound index (unique) around metadata and use an ObjectId for the _id key?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that would be fine. Having the `_id` as it is here looks like it's just for convenience since it will match a URI segment exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Other way ;)

You can create simple collection:

```
{
  "ts": "unix timestamp",
  "site": "site-1",
  "page": "/apache_pb.gif"  
}
```

this collection will be had a very good performance on insert

and using complex aggregate query (with aggregate by any time grain):

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "ts": 1,
      "_id": 0,
      "grain": {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              "$ts",
              3600
            ]
          },
          {
            "$mod": [
              {
                "$divide": [
                  "$ts",
                  3600
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "site": 1,
      "page": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "site": "$site",
        "page": "$page",
        "grain": "$grain",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "tsum": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "_id": {
        "grain": "$_id.grain"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "tsum": "$tsum",
      "_id": 0,
      "grain": "$_id.grain"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "grain": 1
    }
  }
])
```

aggregate your statistics by one hour - 3600 sec in this example

imho - this is a more simple and manageable solution without complex datamodel with good preformance (don't forget about index)

Comment: Well, the good thing to put the dimensions inside a metadata subdocument is that I can add a unique index on metadata, and then I can add any arbitrary dimension without modifying the index.

Comment: And you can also aggregate the statistics by different time periods using an ISODate object and the date aggregation operators http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/ . I don't know which method would be more efficient though.

Comment: In this post, i try to explain how to aggregate data by different  time periods using $project statements for calculating fields ;)